# Webmethod using HttpContext returns null reference exception

Tags: web-services, asmx, nullreferenceexception

It is a web method running via .asmx page:

Quick summary:

```
[WebMethod]

Method Name
{
 string Port=HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
  if (Port == null || Port == "80" || Port == "443")
  {
                    Port = "";
   }
    else
    {
                    Port = ":" + Port;
    }
}
```

When i test this method, i get an exception

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]    'System.Web.HttpContext.Current' is null.
```

1. What conditions httpcontext will be null?
2. Why is it failing the method due to null reference exception?

Does these have anything to do with IIS?

Comment: I've gotten HttpContext in a web service to work with no issues, please post more details.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: ?ex.Message
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
?ex.Data
{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    [System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal]: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    IsFixedSize: false
    IsReadOnly: false
    Keys: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
    Values: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
?ex.InnerException
null

Comment: @Brain, can you share your piece of code for httpcontext request object using server_port?