# HTTPContext for webservices

Tags: c#, web-services

HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT_SECURE"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath

I want to access these value via a webservice -C#, whenever I call these values in webservice I get null for all of the above, where as above works for web pages (aspx).

Comment: could you try adding [WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)] to your web method. I have not tried it though!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Webmethod using HttpContext returns null reference exception.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250129/webmethod-using-httpcontext-returns-null-reference-exception)

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over again.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you need to enable ASP.NET compatibility. You can also enable this via configuration if you don't want to limit your code via attributes like so:

```
<system.serviceModel>        
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

[Here's a great resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx) that helped explain to me the underlying functionality and trade-offs made by enabling compatibility mode.

Comment: Its for wcf & i did now added for asmx's web.config, but did no difference.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of web service are you using? asmx or wcf? They should work fine with asmx services but if you're using WCF, you'll need to add the following attribute to the method:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to define your method with EnableSession at true?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string your_public_method(your_params)
    { [...] }
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a WCF web service you can do the following:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class FooBar : IFooBar
{
   public void DoSomething()
   {
       HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
       if (context != null)
       {
             // Should get here now
       }
   }

}
```

The key is to add `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]`.